# Swift.String to CMutablePointer<CChar>

Tags: c, swift

I've imported and created a bridging header for some old C source code to Swift. The function signature looks like so:

```
struct Message prattle_parse_message(char *line);
```

The swift declaration for it is:

```
func prattle_parse_message(line: CMutablePointer<CChar>) -> Message
```

However, I'm not sure how to convert a Swift `String` (or an `NSString`) to a `CMutablePointer<CChar>` to be passed to this function.

`("Test" as NSString).UTF8String` returns a `CString` which won't work.

Could someone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Perhaps a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084352/cmutablepointercstring-to-string-in-swift-language/24084537#24084537

Comment: @iluvcapra Other way around.

Comment: This one then? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050344/convert-swift-cchar-array-into-a-string .  He uses the NSString(bytes:length:)  but as long as your `line` is null-terminated you can just use NSString(cstring:)

Comment: Does `str.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding).persist()` work ?

Comment: @iluvcapra I'm trying to convert a `String` into a `CMutablePointer<CChar>`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I was under the impression an `Array<CChar>` would be converted when passed to a C function.

Comment: Yeah I see.  You want to turn it INTO a CMutablePointer, not from?

Comment: I'm not sure you'd want to encode with UTF8 string encoding- a `char *` can't hold a UTF-8 string under many implementations, `char *` is usually limited to 7-bit ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* be it...

```
var data =     inString.dataUsingEncoding(encoding, allowsLossyConversion: allow)
var ccharstr = CChar[](count:data.length, repeatedValue:CChar(0))  

data.getBytes(&ccharstr length:data.length)

ccharstr.append(CChar(0))

var message =  prattle_parse_message(&ccharstr)
```

Can't test the last line but I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

prattle_parse_message(str.bridgeToObjectiveC().UTF8String)